# Getting smaller display in emulator?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-emulator

I am creating an app for Archos 7 tablet .I have customized  a emulator for testing the code but when i use that it shows small display.
I have checked the other properties but still i am getting view very small then the real display

Comment: Do you have the "scale display to real size" option checked? If so, make sure that the parameters are correct.

Comment: yes the emulator is  of correct size but as the app starts it shows a small screen

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to add below lines in your manifest file...

```
 <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="4" />

 <supports-screens
    android:anyDensity="true"
    android:largeScreens="true"
    android:normalScreens="true"
    android:smallScreens="true" />
```